# Total amount in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need helping with calculating the total amount of tickets.number in this ng-repeat

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="tickets in listTickets | filter: searchText | orderBy: sortorder:reverse">
    <td>{{ tickets.match }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.number }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.company }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.contact }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.mail }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.phone }}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="edit(tickets._id)">Edit</button> </td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(tickets._id)">Radera</button></td>   
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="8"> Total of: {{ totalTickets() }} tickets</td>
</tr>
```

My controller.js

```
 $scope.totalTickets = function(){

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use filter to calculate a total.

Html

```
<tr ng-repeat="tickets in listTickets | filter: searchText | orderBy: sortorder:reverse">
    <td>{{ tickets.match }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.number }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.company }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.contact }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.mail }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.phone }}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="edit(tickets._id)">Edit</button> </td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(tickets._id)">Radera</button></td>   
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="8"> Total of: <span data-ng-bind="tickets.total=(listTickets | total:'number')"></span> tickets</td>
</tr>
```

Controller.js

```
app.filter('total', function(){
    return function(input, property) {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach(input, function(value, key) { total += parseFloat(value[property]) });
        return total;
    }
})
```

Comment: The filter worked great! Thank you. 

Im all new to Angular, if u have or somebody else have time would u like to walk me trough the angular.forEach?

Answer (score 3):

You can use ECMAScript 5 [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the total sum.

AngularJS method `totalTickets` passing the `filteredArr` array parameter as you are filtering in the view `ng-repeat`:

```
$scope.totalTickets = function (filteredArr) {
  return filteredArr
    .map(function (o) {
        return o.number;
    })
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
};
```

AngularJS view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="tickets in listTickets | filter: searchText as filteredArr | orderBy: sortorder:reverse">
    <td>{{ tickets.match }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.number }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.company }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.contact }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.mail }}</td>
    <td>{{ tickets.phone }}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="edit(tickets._id)">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(tickets._id)">Radera</button></td>   
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="8"> Total of: {{ totalTickets(filteredArr) }} tickets</td>
</tr>
```

Code example:

```js
var listTickets = [{number: 1},{number: 2},{number: 3},{number: 4}],
    total = listTickets.map(o => o.number).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Comment: While this works, the custom filter posted by @aravinthan-k has much better reusability and is the "Angular way".

Comment: Yes @tiblu, it is a better answer to create an AngularJS `filter` and it is more reusable.. Thanks for the good comment!

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution involves the ngRepeat `as` keyword (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and a custom `total` filter as posted by @aravinthan-k.

- `as` keyword has to be last in the filter stack in the `ng-repeat`. Whatever you do in between with different filters, the `as` alias will have the final result.
- `total` filter is easily reusable all over your code.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25g9hzzd/2/

Example HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
   <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <h1>List</h1>
        <input type="text" ng-model="form.searchText"/>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="item in list | filter: form.searchText as result">
            {{item.title}}
          </li>
          <li>TOTAL: {{result | total:'number'}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Example filter (by @aravinthan-k) and the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.filter('total', function(){
    return function(input, property) {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach(input, function(value, key) { total += parseFloat(value[property]) });
        return total;
    }
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.form = {
        searchText: ''
    };

    $scope.list = [
      {
        title: 'A',
        number: 1
      },
      {
        title: 'AB',
        number: 2
      },
      {
        title: 'ABC',
        number: 3
      },
      {
        title: 'ABCD',
        number: 4
      },
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you've filtered the list and need to count only the filtered elements, you'll need to pre filter the list in the controller. You can use the search filter in your controller to pre filter the list.

```
// Inject $filter so that it can be used in the controller
function MyController($filter) {
    $scope.filteredTickets = [];

    // filter the tickets and count how many there are in the filtered list
    function updateTickets(searchTerm) {

        $scope.filteredTickets = $filter('search')($scope.listTickets, $scope.searchText);

        // Use Array.reduce to add up the number of tickets
        $scope.ticketCount = $scope.filteredTickets.reduce(function(count, ticket) {
            return count + ticket.number;
        }, 0);
    }

    // update the ticket count on initialisation
    updateTickets($scope.searchText);

    // update ticket count when search text changes
    $scope.$watch('searchText', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            updateTickets(newValue);
        }
    });
}
```

Then in your HTML you can ng-repeat through the pre filtered tickets, and use the pre calculated total.

```
<tr ng-repeat="tickets in filteredTickets | orderBy: sortorder:reverse">
   ...
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total of {{ ticketCount }} tickets</td>
</tr>
```